# Problem with checkBox

Tags: android, select, checkbox

I have a strange problem with my checkbox. In my adapter I have a TextView, an ImageView and a CheckBox. I had implement a button for select all/deselect all and everything works fine. The problem is that when I select one checkbox, if I scroll the list there are and other checkbox selected(the distance between them is 10) and I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Here is my adapter :

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private String[] data;
        private String[] nume;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader;

        public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] f) {
            activity = a;
            data = d;
            nume = f;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext(),"Folder2");
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            public TextView text;
            public ImageView image;
            public CheckBox ck;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.ck = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
                if (flag)
                    holder.ck.setChecked(true);
                else
                    holder.ck.setChecked(false);

                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

            holder.text.setText(nume[position]);
            holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image);
            return vi;
        }

    }
```

Comment: flag is a boolean. I use it for selectall/deselectall button : selectall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    String txt = textbutton();
    if (txt.equals("Select All")) {
     flag = true;
     selectall.setText("Deselect All");
    } else {
     flag = false;
     selectall.setText("Select All");
    }

    getData();

   }

  });

Comment: Ok, you've accepted incorrect answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views in list are recycled. Your data list may has 100 rows, but `ListView` has only 10 (these visible) rows. When you scroll, rows are recycled. The last row in `ListView` goes to the first position or the other way. You have to change the state of these rows.
You need to keep checkbox state in array, not in views.

Add

```
        final List<Boolean> isCheckedList;
```

initialize it in constructor:

```
        isCheckedList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        for(int i=0;i<myDataLength;i++){
            isCheckedList.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        }
```

and modify getView:

```
        holder.ck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isCheckedList.set(position, holder.ck.isChecked());
            }
        });
```

in place where you fill rows:

```
        holder.ck.setChecked(isCheckedList.get(position));
```

To change state of all checkboxes use:

```
        Collections.fill(isCheckedList, Boolean.FALSE);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I think is ok what you wrote but I get nullpointerexception at line holder.ck.setChecked(isCheckedList.get(position)); Where is the problem?

Comment: You're right, I've corrected the code. Now it works, just tested it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this code:

```
    if (flag)
         holder.ck.setChecked(true);
    else
         holder.ck.setChecked(false);
```

out of your `if{}` block.

Comment: This works only partialy because once I select something from the top of the list and I scroll to the bottom of the list when I get back at the top of the list the item is not selected anymore.It gets unchecked somehow:)Thanks;)