# CheckBox and setOnItemClickListener not working in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onitemclicklistener

I am using `ListView` with `CheckBox`. I have selected only one `CheckBox` but it's automatically selected into Multiple Rows using `ScrollView`.

Sample Code (This Code is working Perfectly)

```
       holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                CheckBox cb = ( CheckBox ) v;
                if ( cb.isChecked() )
                {
                    test[position] = true;
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(test[position]);
                }
                else
                {
                    test[position] = false;
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(test[position]);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(test[position]);
```

But When i uses `setOnItemClickListener` it's not working.

Sample Code (This code is not working for me)

```
        listview.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, final View v, final int position, long id ) 
            {
                holder.checkbox = ( CheckBox ) v.findViewById( R.id.lock_File_CheckBox );
                if ( holder.checkbox.isChecked() )
                {
                    test[position] = false;
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(test[position]);
                }
                else
                {
                    test[position] = true;
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(test[position]);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(test[position]);
```

Where i can mistaken. How do avoid this `CheckBox` Selection.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What is the problem?? Do you want to check more then 1 check-box?

Comment: I have selected One Row but it's point out multiple Row.

Comment: Pardon, I am not getting you.!

Comment: Refer This Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846151/problem-with-checkbox I have a same Problem. When i am using `listview.setOnItemClickListener` it's not working perfectly. That is Now i can First and Second Row (Check Box is Checked) in the same time Last Two Row (CheckBox is Checked). How do solve this.

Comment: When i am using `listview.setOnItemClickListener` to select the CheckBox, In the problem is that when I select one checkbox, if I scroll the list there are and other checkbox selected(the distance between them is 10) and I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have tried your problem and also gotten the fault which you are getting. Then I seen the link posted you above, and solved the problem as there stated. At this time **I have only that SOLUTION, IT MUST HELP YOU**. Thanks for learning new things..

Comment: Now, my experience says, you **MUST** try that accepted answer, **IT REALLY WORKS, I DID IT USING  boolean array**

Comment: I can try and then i send report tomorrow.

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani I workout that concept. In that concept is working fine. But when we have used with `onItemClickListener` in that time it's not responsible. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the instance of CheckBox inside `onItemClick()` by using `setTag()` and `getTag()`. You can setTag the CheckBox instance inside your `getView()` method as

```
convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);
```

And get the instance inside `onItemClick()` using,

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.check);
```

If you have any further query you can check [`my blog post`](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html).

Comment: When i am using listview.setOnItemClickListener to select the CheckBox, In the problem is that when I select one checkbox, if I scroll the list there are and other checkbox selected(the distance between them is 10) and I don't understand why.

Comment: Its happening because of recycling mechanism.

Comment: Checkboxes Randomly Checked/Unchecked in Expandable List, How do avoid recycling mechanism. Can you help me.

Comment: Well, I had already given you my example link, you can download and check how I managed using `setTag()` and `getTag()` by saving the position of ListItem(CheckBox).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for information. Now I can work out, after i inform the result. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. How do sort list. Give me idea. Thanks.

Comment: Lalit  `List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();` How do sort this list at ascending/descending order?

Answer (score 4):

To make your listview focusable, remove focus from the items themselves.
Add the following after instantiating listview:

```
listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

Then add the following to your list_item.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/lock_File_CheckBox"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

With this, your `setOnItemClickListener()` will get called

Answer (score 1):

Don't use onClick. Use OnCheckedChange

```
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                doSomethingWithCheckedState(compoundButton);
            } else {
                doSomethingWithUnCheckedState(compoundButton);
            }
        }
    });
```

Keep in mind that CheckBox inherit from CompoundButton for ICS's switch compatibility.

Comment: Dam `holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener` it's working. But `listview.setOnItemClickListener` it's not working.

Comment: Right. So the problem is not coming from you sample code, but from your adapter. If there is multiple CheckBox being selected, it must be a reference problem.

Comment: When I am select a First Row CheckBox can be checked First and Twelth Row. When I am select a Second Row CheckBox can be checked Second and Thirteen Row. Why it's happened.

Answer (score 0):

Focusable view in the list item prevents the firing of `onListItemClick()` in the `ListActivity` when the list item is clicked. But the effect of `onListItemClick()` can be achieved with `OnClickListener`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/android-how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list) more about this